# How can I include python code in clojure?

Tags: python, clojure

I want to import a Keras model from python to Clojure. Does anybody know an easy way to do it? I've heard about libpython-clj but couldn't find a good resource to learn it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[libpython-clj](https://github.com/clj-python/libpython-clj) is just what you are looking for. they have well-documented [examples](https://github.com/gigasquid/libpython-clj-examples), [unitests](https://github.com/clj-python/libpython-clj/tree/master/test/libpython_clj) and a slack-channel on [clojurians](https://clojurians.slack.com/messages) **#libpython-clj**

so far keras you can do (example taken from [here](https://msync.org/notes/python-clj-ml/)):

```
(ns machine-learning-notes.hello-ml
    (:require [libpython-clj.python :as py]
              [libpython-clj.jna.base]))

(alter-var-root #'libpython-clj.jna.base/*python-library* (constantly "python3.7m"))
(py/initialize! :python-executable (str (System/getenv "HOME") "/.venv/ml/bin/python"))

(require [libpython-clj.require :refer [require-python]])
  (require-python [tensorflow :as tf]
                  [tensorflow.keras.models :as models]
                  [tensorflow.keras.layers :as layers]
                  [tensorflow.keras.datasets.mnist :as mnist]
                  [numpy :as numpy]
                  [builtins :as python])

(defonce mnist-data (mnist/load_data))

  (let [[[x-train y-train] [x-test y-test]] mnist-data] ;; => 1
    (def x-train (numpy/divide x-train 255)) ;; => 2
    (def y-train y-train)
    (def x-test (numpy/divide x-test 255))
    (def y-test y-test))

(defonce model (models/Sequential [(layers/Flatten :input_shape [28 28]) ;; => 3
                                     (layers/Dense 128 :activation "relu")
                                     (layers/Dropout 0.2)
                                     (layers/Dense 10 :activation "softmax")]))

(py/py. model compile ;; 4, 5
          :optimizer "adam"
          :loss "sparse_categorical_crossentropy"
          :metrics (python/list ["accuracy"])) ;; 6
(py/py. model fit x-train y-train :epochs 5)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!